# How to write for loops with multiplicative increment in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have seen python tutorials on loops but none of them shows this way of looping that is shown below.

Is it possible to convert this python? Or Is there any other way to do this?

```
 for(int i=1;i<=64;i=i*2)
           cout<<i;
```

---

```
 //i know these following in python
 for i in range(1,64,2) // moves i in steps of 2
 for i in range(64,1,-1) // moves i in down steps of 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific case of doubling each time, or for other regular sequences, you can use comprehension to achieve the same effect:

```
for i in (2**i for i in range(0, 7)): print i
```

Note that this is really just the same as:

```
for i in range(0, 7): print 2**i
```

In more general cases, however, you can use a `while` loop, as shown in another answer, or create your own [generator function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) for use in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the first option you mentioned only if you want to increment i by 2 each time, i.e:

```
for i in range (1,65,2):
```

pay attention that if you want i to also be equel to 64 you have to end your range at 65.
the other option is you want i to be doubled each time:

```
i=1
while i<=64:
    #some code comes here
    i*=2
```

once again if you want 64 to be part of the loop you need to see where the loop ends (i.e at what value of i)